# How to make a U shape Scroll in React

Tags: html, reactjs, scroll

So i was thinking to make a web page who has a u shape Scroll. i tried to draw a concept of it in the image below

The black arrows are when you scroll down ,orange arrows when u scroll back and the red number the order of the screens are supposed to show. I saw some examples but didn't see anything to make the page scroll in reverse.

I was thinking to make 6 screens and when the scroll is detected it goes to the other screen directly with a smooth scroll, or you can make it like a regular scroll with the function to scroll in a "U" shape.

I'm still new at this and don't know how to implement and work with scroll. If somebody have a solution for this would highly appreciate it.

[image]

Comment: You will need a scroll event, and you will need to use `transform: translate3d(x, y, z)` to move the screen around. I would use that together with css variables, and the css variables would be updated from the scroll event. You can play with that to get the desired behavior.

Comment: This a good example of using translate3d on a section of a page that reacts to a scroll event https://www.frank-studio.com/work/dg-melt-e-commerce-minisite/